# WP_Query won't return one of the custom post types when multiple post types requested

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm registering multiple custom post types. One is 'news', the second is lets say 'notification'. I'm registering both (and many others) with:

news:

```
$labels = .. // leaving this blank for SO, shouldn't be of importance

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'news' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions' )
);

register_post_type( 'news', $args );
```

notification:

```
$labels = .. // leaving this blank for SO, shouldn't be of importance

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'notification' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions' ),
    'can_export'         => true,
    'taxonomies'         => array('employee'),
);

register_post_type( 'notification', $args );
```

}

If I try to get for instance 'news' and 'post' post types (or 'news' and 'event' etc) like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('news','post'),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

it will do what it should: get all posts of the types given in post_type array param.

However, when I try to get any post type WITH 'notification' post type, it won't return 'notification' post types. Examples I tried:

> 'post_type' => array('news','post'), // news AND posts get returned
>
> 'post_type' => array('news','notification'), // news get returned, but not notifications
>
> 'post_type' => array('post','notification'), // only posts get returned

When passing only 'notification' post type I get the posts returned as I should:

> 'post_type' => array('notification'), // I get all notifications

**Why won't I receive any post of type 'notification' if any other post type is present in post_type array?** There must be something ridiculously obvious I'm missing here.

The only difference when registering news and notification is 'can_export' and 'taxonomies' but that is not it (tried commenting this out for notification)

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Ok so I think I have the culprit: Polylang Plugin. If deactivated, this works as it should. Any ideas?!

Comment: Have you checked that `$labels` is a valid array for the `'notification'` post type?...Not sure that would matter at all anyways.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is: it's the same as for 'news' and other post types

Comment: Just a thought, you might have a conflict with core terms. Have you tried renaming notification to notifications or something else. Remember to reflush rewrite rules aftr the changes

Comment: Notifications is not a reserved post type http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Reserved_Post_Types but I'm guessing you are using a plugin that possibly created this? Can you try with plugins disabled?

Comment: I'm not using a plugin to do this, I'm creating post types manually in code :'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I got it. Absolutely ridiculous as expected.

One of the custom post types was not translated and checked in Polylang Settings because it was added after the plugin was configured.

> Settings->Languages->Settings->Custom post types

Damn.

Comment: Man...you just saved me!! The thing is that i have to disable polylang but finally i could solve this! Thanks a lot!